# How can you group multiple answer fields?

Tags: 6, entities

Firstly, apologies if I don't use correct Drupal or database terminology - I'm still learning!

I am using Drupal 6 with the latest stable versions of CCK, Views and Date.

I have a content type that requires two 'sections' of fields - the first would be for standard fields, the second would be multiple entry fields where all the fields are related.

It's probably best explained with an example, so here goes:

Let's say the content type is for episodes of a TV show.

Firstly, we want to know the title of the episode, so there'll be a title field.

Secondly, we want a reference number for the episode, so there'll be an ID field.

Now for the grouped fields:

We want to know when the episode was broadcast, and on what channel.  However, it may be that the episode is repeated - and that repeat could be on another channel.  For example:

Top Gear was on BBC2 this evening (26/06/11) at 8pm.  It will be repeated on BBC2 on 28/06/11 at 11.20pm.  It will be repeated again on 29/06/11 at 7pm, this time on BBC3.

So I want to have an unlimited value datetime field.  However, this needs to be bound to an unlimited value text field for the channel (and likewise for any other field with unlimited value data).

How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!  Please bear in mind that I'm not much more than a novice - I can install a module but I won't know how to do any advanced stuff without guidance!

Answer (score 2):

The drupal 6 version of cck comes with a sub-module called multigroup. This will allow you to group multiple fields together and allow for unlimited inputs per group.

Comment: Note that multigroup support is only in the 6.x-3.0 alpha release.

Comment: Thanks!  However, the closest thing I can see within CCK is Fieldgroup.  Do you mean that?  I also searched the Drupal site, and couldn't find a multigroup module.  When I enable fieldgroup, I can create a group, but it just shows up in the fields list.  How do I use a group?  Am I even using the right thing?

Comment: fieldgroup is not the same as multigroup. As @Dylan Tack noted, you must be using the 3.0 alpha release and also must enable the multigroup sub module. Once this is done you will have the multigroup option in fields.

Comment: Ah sorry, I don't know how I missed that bit!  OK, I've updated to the alpha and enabled Content Multigroup.  I've created a multigroup, but once again I don't see how to put fields in it, and it just shows up in the orderable list much like a field.  How do I use it?

Comment: Never mind, I've found how it works!  Thanks for the help!  I'm now getting an error when I go to create content of that type, I get an error message in a pink box at the top of the page.  I've posted the error in my original post.  How do I get rid of this?

Comment: This is now a new issue (and beyond the scope of this site as your issue pertains to the module itself) and should be posted in the issue queue for the cck module. And as you can see it is a known issue. Please refer to these posts for any help http://drupal.org/node/1096776 and https://drupal.org/node/1189090

Comment: With respect, this was not an issue prior to my installing multigroup, so I would consider it entirely relevant.  Or should I have specified that I wanted a solution that doesn't throw up errors?  With regard to patching it, I have no idea how to do that (as I said, I'm new to this) - I don't use Linux and I have no access to it via my shared hosting package.

Comment: In fact, installing this alpha has made this content type unusable.  I have another field that uses a node reference (where I type in something and it gives a drop-down list).  When this happens, the drop-down list won't go away and I can't submit my data.  This is precisely why I was only using stable releases of modules such as CCK, as stated in my original post.  I'm sure you'll tell me that this is a new issue and I need to post on drupal.org, but I'm sorry - this only happened since you suggested using this alpha and I'm not happy with the outcome.

Comment: wow. i am not sure where to start with your comments. I think you need to learn more about Drupal and more importantly how the Drupal community works. I understand that you are new to Drupal but I think you should spend some time reading the FAQ http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq of this site and more importantly some Drupal etiquette http://drupal.org/dcoc. Thank you and have a good day.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way.  However, your first answer was not helpful as you didn't notice I said I use the latest STABLE release - you didn't mention I would need the alpha.  You then didn't explain how multigroup worked - I did state I'm a novice.  Is this not a help site?  The solution you gave has given me a lot of NEW errors, which you won't help me solve.  Sorry, whilst I respect your superior knowledge, how am I supposed to feel about this?  I hoped that asking further questions would solve the issue - obviously I'm wrong.

Comment: As per your etiquette (not even part of this site, though), I showed you respect.  I asked for help when I was unsure.  And I felt that I didn't get the help I requested.  I have always been civil to you - I merely stated that I'm not happy with the resolution you suggested (i.e. seeking help off-site).  I believe I have fully conformed to your FAQ and etiquette guide - if you feel I haven't, then please feel free to flag this for review.  If anyone else can help with my issue, I'd be happy to hear.  I hope I don't have to start from scratch to iron out the alpha bugs!

Comment: Feel free to downvote my answer, restore your site from the backup that you should have made (as part of any drupal dev best practices) and wait for someone else to provide you with an answer. I am done here.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I would have thought you'd know that I don't have the reputation to downvote - sadly this is reserved for those who have lots of reputation, i.e. those knowledgable enough to reply.  I hadn't made a backup as I wasn't technically that far into making my site, dealing with the structure first, although I had some sample data that would have been used in the final site.  I wasn't at a stage where I thought a backup was necessary - obviously this is something I'll think about in future when trying alpha modules.